# How to render the quill js content using go buffalo framework

Tags: javascript, go, quill, buffalo

The options that i am aware of are,

1. Get the content of the quilljs from `getContents` api which gives the JSON structure. I can post this to server and store it in server.
2. Get the innerHTML of the `div` which is passed to Quill editor and store it.

**Approach 1:**

While displaying it back I need to write the content in my buffalo template in a variable like

`<script> var contentJSON = "<%= content %>"</script>`

Then once the page loaded I need to set the contents like `quillInstance.setContents(contentJSON)`

**Approach 2:**

Incase the request is compromised then the html may contain scripts unescaped. So if I try like this

```
c.Set("getContent", func(content string) template.HTML {
    return template.HTML(html.EscapeString(content))
})
```

This escapes all the html entities. So all the div, styles introduced by quill js also gone with this. So the whole content looks just like a plain string.

Whats the right approach in storing the content? I am looking for a way to get this rendered in the server.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i end with the following,

```
Helpers: render.Helpers{
            "quil_for": func(content string) template.HTML {
                content = strings.ReplaceAll(content, "<script>", "&lt;script&gt;")
                content = strings.ReplaceAll(content, "<a>", "&lt;a&gt;")
                content = strings.ReplaceAll(content, "</a>", "&lt;/a&gt;")
                content = strings.ReplaceAll(content, "</script>", "&lt;/script&gt;")
                return template.HTML(content)
            },
        },
```

instead of this

```
c.Set("getContent", func(content string) template.HTML {
    return template.HTML(html.EscapeString(content))
})
```

This escapes only the script and the anchor tag and the res of html as it is.